# how to send the notification to the user whoose journey date is reached

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

how to send the notification to the user whose journey date is reached that means current date matches the booking date using Firebase cloud function.[this is my db structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Oqdl.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I believe a similar concern was addressed in this [Stackoverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47252076/notify-user-when-a-date-is-near#answer-47416889). And as advised, you could schedule a [Cron Job with Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/how-to-schedule-cron-jobs-with-cloud.html)