# How to schedule recurring notifications in kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-notifications

I've been looking for this for a couple of hours but I haven't found anything helpful. Right now, I have an activity (called other_recurringreminder) that sets a time (fomartted calendar, HH:mm; string), repetition frequency (int), repetition unit (like minutes, hours, days; string), whether it's on or off (bool), and a name (string)

In other_recurringreminder.kt, I have this function:

```
fun sendnotification()
{
     val channelID = "channel1"
     val notificationID = 1
     val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
     val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "channelID")
         .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.centr)
         .setColor(resources.getColor(R.color.purple))
         .setContentTitle(sharedPreferences.getString("Alarm1Name_USERPREFS", "Reminder 1"))
         .setContentText(getString(R.string.notif_recurringreminders))
         .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
         .setAutoCancel(true)

     with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(this)) {
         notify(notificationID, builder.build())
     }
 }
```

Which sends the notification when called.
How can I make it so that my app sends this notification at a time from SharedPreferences, with a title from SP, and repeats every x units from SP?
Should this function be in another kotlin file?
Can this work even after a restart, when my app hasn't yet been opened?If I want to schedule more than one notif with different values, do I need to duplicate anything?
Sorry if it's a dumb question, I'm fairly new to kotlin. and thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can use alarm manager for it.
first create a class with broadcast receiver like

```
                class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
                
                    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent?) {
                        Log.d("this", "notify")
                
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                
                            val intent = Intent(context, AlarmActivity2::class.java)
                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
                            val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0)
                
                            val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "111")
                                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.blue_stringart)
                                .setContentTitle("Alarm is running")
                                .setAutoCancel(true)
                                .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL)
                                .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                                .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
                                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_baseline_stop_24,"Stop",pendingIntent)
                                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                
                            val notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM)
                            val r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, notification)
                            r.play()
                
                            val notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)
                            notificationManagerCompat.notify(123, builder.build())
                
                        }
                
                    }
                
                }
```

after that go to your activity  class make 2 method and call in oncreate

```
            private fun setAlarm1() {
            var calender: Calendar
          calender = Calendar.getInstance()
                        calender.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, PUT_YOUR_ALARM HOUR)
                        calender.set(Calendar.MINUTE, PUT_YOUR_ALARM MINUTE)
                        calender.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
                    alarmManager = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
                    val thuReq: Long = Calendar.getInstance().timeInMillis + 1
                    var reqReqCode = thuReq.toInt()
                    if (calender.timeInMillis < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
                        calender.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1)
                    }
                    val alarmTimeMilsec = calender.timeInMillis
                    val intent = Intent(this, AlarmReceiver::class.java)
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK)
                    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, reqReqCode, intent, 0)
            
                    alarmManager.setRepeating(
                        AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                        calender.timeInMillis,
                       HERE_PUT_YOUR_HOUR * 60 * 60 * 1000,
                        pendingIntent
                    )
    
    
        private fun createNotificationChannel() {
    
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                val name = "Alarmclock Channel"
                val description = " Reminder Alarm manager"
                val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
                val notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(CHANNELID, name, importance)
                notificationChannel.description = description
                val notificationManager =
                    getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
            }
        }
```

Note - ***Must to do***(go to your app setting and give notification permission  on) 1.alarmManager.setRepeating here you can use your alarm type as your wish. 2.requestcode must be unique for each alarm. 3. you must take a alarm time and keep in calender.timeInMillis which is you expecting alarm time.

still problem comments below